# CSS link styling priority

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to style some of my link on my website I'm making for school, but I've ran into a problem. One bit is styled with CSS so its can be used as navigation menu. The other links are regular links with some styling.
The navigation menu has to be in the div tag for the regular link styling too, otherwise the background will not cover the whole page.

The problem is, since the div of the nav menu is placed within the styling of the other links, the effect of both styles get applied to the navigation menu.

Is there a way to give the styling of the navigation menu a higher priority than those of the other links, so that only the styling of the navigation menu will be applied?

Here's the CSS of the navigation menu:

```
    /* styling voor navigation menu */

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #525252;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 400;
    margin-right: 400;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black ;
    color: #fff;
    }

.nav li {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
    background-color: #404040;
}

.nav a.active {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}

.nav li {
    width: 110px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

    /* extra class voor meescrollen menubalk */

 .main-nav-scrolled {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    text-align: center;
    width: 41%;
    background: #858585
    }
```

here's the CSS of the other links:

```
/* links voor onderste gedeelte pagina */

.bottom a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.bottom a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.bottom a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.bottom a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

And here is the important bit of HTML:

```
    <div class="bottom">
    <!-- navigation balk bovenin pagina -->
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="Pokémon"><a class="active" href="SQLpokemondb.php">Pokémon</a></li>
        <li class="Types"><a href="Over ons.html">Types</a></li>
        <li class="Abilities"><a href="Sponsoren.html">Abilities</a></li>
        <li class="Natures"><a href="Kleding.html">Natures</a></li>
        <li class="Stats"><a href="Vacaturen.html">Stats</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<?php
echo " <span style='color:$color'><a href='SQLdetailtypendb.php?id=" . $data['type_id'] . "'>" . $type1 . '</span></a>';    
?>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!
-Gijs

Comment: Can you show me an example of where you have your regular `a` links in your html? The ones you are styling in the second CSS section you posted.

Comment: You can use `!important` to overwrite other. Ex. `color: #fff !important;`

Comment: @Phantom that would work but usually a pretty terrible solution and should be avoided if necessary.

Comment: Yes...I know...but you have the css which overwrite others...

Comment: @JalenDavenport I've added a bit of the link in the HTML part of the code

Comment: Just use a more specific selector ... `.bottom .nav a { … }`

Comment: @G.Man cool let me see what I can do.

Comment: @Phantom I also tried to use the !important in CSS on a few places but didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @CBroe doesn't seem to be working either

Comment: @Phantom I hope that you don't suggest to use `!important` anymore in the future. It's reaaaallllyyyy annoying if it's present in the stylesheet. It's considered as bad practice in most situations because it breaks the specificity (which often shows bad design).

Comment: @MihaiT so like: `.bottom .nav ul li a:hover { background-color: #404040;}` ? If yes, tried it, but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @KarelG Ok...Thank you for suggestion of good practice. I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add styles to `.bottom a` that are not given to `.bottom .nav a` like `background: green` it will become a style to `.bottom .nav a` also. All styles need to be overwritten if you want custom styles only for `.bottom .nav a`

because `.nav a` is a descendant of `.bottom` , even if you write a very specific path eg `.bottom .nav ul li a` , it will inherit from `.bottom a` 
the styles that are 'unique'

for example

1. snippet not good for you ( `.nav li a` inheriting `background: green` style from `.bottom a` because it doesn't have a `background` style for its self )

```css
.bottom .nav a:hover { color:red;}
.bottom a:hover { color:yellow;background:green}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
    <!-- navigation balk bovenin pagina -->
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="Pokémon"><a class="active" href="SQLpokemondb.php">Pokémon</a></li>
        <li class="Types"><a href="Over ons.html">Types</a></li>
        <li class="Abilities"><a href="Sponsoren.html">Abilities</a></li>
        <li class="Natures"><a href="Kleding.html">Natures</a></li>
        <li class="Stats"><a href="Vacaturen.html">Stats</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. snippet good ( disable background:green from `.bottom a` by adding `background:none` or `background: anythinghere image or color etc.` for `.bottom .nav li a` )

```css
.bottom .nav a:hover { color:red;background:black}
.bottom a:hover { color:yellow;background:green}
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
    <!-- navigation balk bovenin pagina -->
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
        <li class="Pokémon"><a class="active" href="SQLpokemondb.php">Pokémon</a></li>
        <li class="Types"><a href="Over ons.html">Types</a></li>
        <li class="Abilities"><a href="Sponsoren.html">Abilities</a></li>
        <li class="Natures"><a href="Kleding.html">Natures</a></li>
        <li class="Stats"><a href="Vacaturen.html">Stats</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: " All styles need to be overwritten if you want custom styles only for `.bottom .nav a` " this was the problem, thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So what you're going to want to do first is add a new class to all the links in your `nav`, for example:

```
<li class="Types"><a class="new-class-here" href="Over ons.html">Types</a></li>
```

Then in your css for the nav you will use `.nav a.new-class-here` instead of `.nav a`, `.nav a.new-class-here:hover` instead of `.nav a:hover`, and so forth.

Then in your css for the other regular links you will want to use `.bottom a:not(.new-class-here)` instead of `.bottom a`. What this does is selects all the links in `.bottom` that do not have that new class we created. So now your nav styles will only apply to your nav links and your regular styles will only apply to the non-nav links.

You can learn more about `:not()` here if you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not